# TypeError: $.mainBowerFiles is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp

I've very little experience with modern web-app development using the latest Javascript frameworks and toolchains.

I installed a toolchain and scaffolding with the 'Gulp Angular' yeoman generator. I believe that the original build worked fine.

Now, `gulp serve` works ok, but attempting to build a distribution (`gulp build`) results in:

`TypeError: $.mainBowerFiles is not a function`

How can I get my distribution build working again?

**Gulp file:**

```
/**
 *  Welcome to your gulpfile!
 *  The gulp tasks are split into several files in the gulp directory
 *  because putting it all here was too long
 */

'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var wrench = require('wrench');

/**
 *  This will load all js or coffee files in the gulp directory
 *  in order to load all gulp tasks
 */
wrench.readdirSyncRecursive('./gulp').filter(function(file) {
  return (/\.(js|coffee)$/i).test(file);
}).map(function(file) {
  require('./gulp/' + file);
});


/**
 *  Default task clean temporaries directories and launch the
 *  login optimization build task
 */
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
  gulp.start('build');
});
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
"name": "vweb",
"version": "0.0.0",
"dependencies": {},
"scripts": {
  "test": "gulp test"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "estraverse": "~4.1.0",
  "gulp": "~3.9.0",
  "gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.0.2",
  "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~1.8.0",
  "del": "~2.0.2",
  "lodash": "~3.10.1",
  "gulp-cssnano": "~2.1.1",
  "gulp-filter": "~3.0.1",
  "gulp-flatten": "~0.2.0",
  "gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
  "eslint-plugin-angular": "~0.12.0",
  "gulp-load-plugins": "~0.10.0",
  "gulp-size": "~2.0.0",
  "gulp-uglify": "~1.4.1",
  "gulp-useref": "~3.0.3",
  "gulp-util": "~3.0.6",
  "gulp-ng-annotate": "~1.1.0",
  "gulp-replace": "~0.5.4",
  "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
  "gulp-rev": "~6.0.1",
  "gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
  "gulp-htmlmin": "~1.3.0",
  "gulp-inject": "~3.0.0",
  "gulp-protractor": "~2.1.0",
  "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.6.0",
  "gulp-sass": "~2.0.4",
  "gulp-angular-filesort": "~1.1.1",
  "main-bower-files": "~2.9.0",
  "wiredep": "~2.2.2",
  "karma": "~0.13.10",
  "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
  "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.1",
  "phantomjs": "~1.9.18",
  "karma-angular-filesort": "~1.0.0",
  "karma-phantomjs-shim": "~1.2.0",
  "karma-coverage": "~0.5.2",
  "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.2.0",
  "browser-sync": "~2.9.11",
  "browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.3",
  "http-proxy-middleware": "~0.9.0",
  "chalk": "~1.1.1",
  "uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
  "wrench": "~1.5.8"
},
"engines": {
  "node": ">=0.10.0"
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the contents of gulpfile.js and package.json.

Comment: @Barryman9000 done

Comment: You probably need this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-main-bower-files

Comment: @kazenorin It's already included in his `package.json` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've `"gulp-load-plugins"` installed, but it's nowhere mentioned in your `gulpfile.js`. The purpose of this module to load all the required modules so that individual `require` is not required.

You should add following, before calling `$.mainBowerFiles`.

```
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
    pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*', 'main-bower-files'],
    replaceString: /\bgulp[\-.]/
});
```

Here, `main-bower-files` needs to be injected manually in pattern and you can use wildcards as well if other modules have similar name.